# Winform DataGridView Control With Extended Capabilities

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am looking for a DataGridView control for Winforms which has the following capabilities with little or no programming (once the the control is bound to datasource).

- Disconnected Search/Filtering
- Pagination
- Backend/Frontend Column Groupping
- Exporting Data
- Print Preview

It doesn't matter the control be commercial, free, or open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try the [Telerik GridView](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx) it pretty much does all you want except for the Print preview.

Comment: Could you please suggest me other control(s) having the print preview capability.

Comment: I could not find paging in Telerik Gridview.

Comment: @NickBinnet Paging is not available in the Gridview